# Perform sed operations on given line numbers

Tags: sed

I am wondering whether there is a simple way to operate on certain lines with preassigned line numbers.

Let's say I want to output the 1st, 7th, 14th and 16th lines of a file, I can simply do

```
sed -n '1p;7p;14p;16p' input_file
```

but this gets more complicated when the operation is not just printing, and I don't want to write the same long command 4 times (and yes, I know I can construct this long sed command by substituting the same bash variable 4 times, but that's not ideal enough ...) , i.e.

```
sed -n '1{long_command};7{long_command};14{long_command};16{long_command}' input_file
```

Is there a way to do the operation on these specific lines of my file? I am expecting something like,

```
sed -n '1,7,14,16p'
```

which certainly will not work in the current form.

Any help will be appreciated. "No, it is not possible." with explanations is also an answer that I will accept.

Comment: it's easy with `awk`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use branches:

```
sed '
  1b1
  7b1
  14b1
  16b1

  # for the rest to be left alone, branch off (or delete them with "d"):
  b

  :1
  long_command'
```

(note that you can also add some `20,25b1` line ranges, or `/re/b1` to include lines that match the `re`).

Or you could use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || NR == 7 || ... {stuff}'
```

Or using a hash:

```
awk -v l=1,7,14,16 '
  BEGIN{split(l, a, ","); for (i in a) lines[a[i]]}

  NR in lines {stuff}'
```

(or `BEGIN{lines[1]lines[7]lines[14]lines[16]}` if there aren't too many)

Comment: Thank you, never thought of branches ... It just seem to be the ideal tool to use in this case.

Comment: how do use branches like this in sed with a search pattern? like say I wanna match or delete a pattern after the nth line?

Answer (score 3):

Simply invert your selection and delete it:

```
sed '2,6d;8,13d;15d;17,$d;long_command'
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution although a little harder for handling line numbers that are read from stdin, for example.

Answer (score 1):

#### First variant:

You can use this trick:

```
sed -nf <(printf '%dp\n' 1 7 14 16)
```

> **-f** **script-file** - add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed.

**Testing**

```
seq 1 20 | sed -nf <(printf '%dp\n' 1 7 14 16)
```

**Output**

```
1
7
14
16
```

#### Second variant:

In the beginning, the auxiliary `sed` is used for filtering only needed lines from the file, then these lines piped to the main `sed` with the long command.

```
sed -n '1p; 7p; 14p; 16p' input.txt | sed 'long command'
```